# Android - crash while embedding Line SDK into framework

Tags: android, crash

all.

I'm trying add Line native login to a framework, which already has Facebook and Google native login. Here are the instructions: https://developers.line.me/android/development-with-sdk-v2

The code is as following:

```
    Context context = GSAPI.getInstance().getContext();

    Intent loginIntent = LineLoginApi.getLoginIntent(activity.getApplicationContext(), channelID);

    activity.startActivityForResult(loginIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

When running the framework at testing app and starting the activity, there is a crash:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.denistester, PID: 614
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method startActivity(Landroid/app/Activity;Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/os/Bundle;)V in class Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat' appears in /data/app/com.example.denistester-1/base.apk)
    at com.linecorp.linesdk.auth.internal.c$c.onPostExecute(SourceFile:1125)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Please,advise.

Answer (score 0):

solving this problem, because you miss compile in build.gradle, so you should add this line

> compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.4.0'

in your build.gradle.

Link document: https://developers.line.me/android/development-with-sdk-v2